# Applying for the Short-Term Study visa UK but there is problem

Tags: visas, uk, study, vfs-global

I'm already applying my application for the UK Short-Term Study via the online and made an appointment but if I chosen the prime time service there is notice below the page said I should pay the fee by VFS website but my problem is when I created an account at VFS website there is information request page and when I select the visa type I didn't find the Short-Term Study visa, you can find which visas I found on the page at attachment.

I'll contact the VFS but that maybe take a long time for their response,so in your experience which visa type as you see on the attachment is closer to the Short-Term Study visa?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]